# Is there a formula for Golems' state growth?

Tags: ps3, enchanted-arms

Golems are a huge part of EA, but after using one for so long, I find its stats are so much higher than the ones I haven't used, it would be silly to switch. Especially when you haven't even synth'd the golem yet.

What I want to know is if anyone has a guide or **formula for determining stat growth  for golems** (due to level up) or if it is just random?

This would help me determine if leveling up a new golem would be worth it, if it has a greater stat growth and similar role (defensive, offensive, etc.) then I could swap it in knowing long term there would be an advantage.

I looked at this guide: [Golem Guide](http://www.gamefaqs.com/xbox360/928678-enchanted-arms/faqs/44742) from Gamefaqs, but it doesn't mention any of this, just has base stats.

Comment: Huh, Jon was right. You really do lose the ability to rollback if your revision is trampled like that.

Comment: Just as a note, the entire Prima Strategy Guide is posted online, but I can't seem to find any notes about the stat growth... http://www.spumonte.com/files/pdfs/Game%20Guides/Xbox%20360%20Guides/Enchanted%20Arms%20(Official%20Prima%20Guide).pdf